# how can i put a JButton on an image?

Tags: java, swing, size, jbutton, paintcomponent

I am trying to fix a JFrame where there will be a background image and on the image JButtons which will do some commands.  I try to do it without layout because i want to put small buttons in some specific locations on the JFrame but every time i do it, the background image comes to the front or the JFrame has size equal to the JFrame size. With the following code, the JButton has the same size to JFrame. I have tried to change the size and location of the JButton but nothing. Can you help me please?

here is the code

```
public final class Test extends JComponent
{
 private Image background;
 private JFrame frame;
 private Dimension dimension;
```

```
public Test()
{  
    dimension = new Dimension(15, 15);
    frame = new JFrame("Iphone");
    frame.pack();
    frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    frame.getContentPane().add(this);
    frame.setBounds(641, 0, 344, 655);
    frame.setVisible(true);

    test = displayButton("tigka");
    frame.getContentPane().add(test);
}

public void update(Graphics g)
{
    paint(g);
}


public void paintComponent(Graphics g)
{
    super.paintComponents(g);
    g.drawImage(background, 0, 25, null); // draw background
```

//        label();

test = displayButton("test");
}

public JButton displayButton(String name)
{
    JButton button = new JButton(name);

    button.setSize(100, 100);
    button.setPreferredSize(dimension);
    return button;
}

Comment: get rid of the update() method. There is no need to override this method in Swing. That is old code for AWT and should not be used in a Swing application.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to change the `content pane` to get a background for your `Frame`.

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {

    JFrame frame = new JFrame("Test");

    frame.setContentPane(new JPanel() {
        BufferedImage image = ImageIO.read(new URL("http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/en/2/24/Lenna.png"));
        public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
            super.paintComponent(g);
            g.drawImage(image, 0, 0, 300, 300, this);
        }
    });

    frame.add(new JButton("Test Button"));

    frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    frame.setSize(300, 300);
    frame.setVisible(true);
}
```

Output:

[image: screenshot]

Comment: wrong: (might be a typo) the super method to call is paintComponent instead of paintComponent**s**

Comment: and now reverse the order of calls again ;-)

Comment: @dacwe @kleopatra if you change it to the paintComponent (which I think is right) then it should be used as first to do all the default painting over which you then want to draw your image. Test it yourselves.

Comment: @Boro, that's what I meant - see my comment to Thomas' answer - was too lazy to repeat it here :-)

Comment: @kleopatra yea. I have seen it but later. I have plus-ed it too. Sorry for the repeat. BTW +1 @dacwe very nice answer and great example.

Comment: @Kleopatra: Your tip is both correct! When i first wrote this code, due to fill code option of net beans, it was filled with paintComponents, but the code seemed to work correctly! After some other programming works in the same code, i realised that it was written as paintComponents, and changed it with paintComponent. Everything was working great with both methods so i did not search for answers about it (maybe this was wrong). Do you know what is the difference?

Comment: I changed the code and i can see that there is no background image with the paintComponent() method but it works correctly with paintComponents() one... :S

Comment: I suggest you change `null` to `this` as the `JPanel` is an image observer.

Comment: when I try to position button to some location x,y it doesnt work.Please reply

Comment: @RajTrivedi your comment doesn't contribute to this question/answer, write another question and I'm happy to answer it.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried using a JLabel with HTML in the label? Something like this:

```
import javax.swing.*;

public class SwingImage1
{
  public static void main( String args[] )
  {
    JFrame  frm = new JFrame( "Swing Image 1" );
    JLabel  lbl = new JLabel( "<html><body><img src=\"http://liv.liviutudor.com/images/liv.gif\"></body></html>" );
    frm.getContentPane().add( lbl );
    frm.setDefaultCloseOperation( JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE );
    frm.pack();
    frm.setVisible( true );
  }
}
```

then on top of your label you can add your button?

Comment: Actually this is a different method of solving this problem. It will help with me the problem i have now but i think that it will also change many thinkg later. Thank you for your answer though

Comment: -1 for using html where not needed ... create and set an ImageIcon instead. Plus using a JLabel at all isn't a good idea: the requirement is to have a _background_ under the normal components which are added ...

Answer (score 1):

You should swap those two lines:

```
super.paintComponents(g);  //paints the children, like the button
g.drawImage(background, 0, 25, null); // draw background later possibly overwriting the button
```

Thus it should be this order:

```
g.drawImage(background, 0, 25, null);
super.paintComponents(g);
```

Additionally, note that the content pane's default layout is BorderLayout. Thus you'd set the layout of your content pane to null explicitly.

Comment: This was a very helpfull answer because i did not know about the default layout of the content pane. thank you. Regarding the first tip, what is the difference?

Comment: There is no difference in my post, just your code with comments and the hint to swap them. :)

Comment: never touch awt painting methods in Swing JComponents ;-) So it's a -1 except for having been helpful in that it completely puzzled me - because calling super.paintComponent *before* custom paint code **is** the sequence to implement (otherwise, the custom paint would be over-painted with the background for opaque components)

Comment: Yes, this would be the correct sequence, but he called `super.paintComponents` not `super.paintComponent`. Besides that you're right in not calling that method manually but rather calling `paintComponent` (didn't recognize that as a potential typo :) ).

Answer (score 0):

```
/*it is simple to put button on image first set image by making object then make button object & add the button object direct to image object rather then add to frame.*/

package frame;



import javax.swing.ImageIcon;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;

public class frame 
{

    public frame() 
    {
        JFrame obj = new JFrame("Banking Software");
        JButton b1 = new JButton("Opening Account");
        JLabel image = new JLabel(new ImageIcon("money.jpg"));
        image.setBounds(0,0, 1600, 1400);
        obj.setExtendedState(JFrame.MAXIMIZED_BOTH);
        obj.add(image);
        b1.setBounds(500,400, 100, 40);
        image.add(b1);
        obj.setVisible(true);
    }

    public static void main(String args[]) 
    {
        new frame();
    }
}
```