# Adding a background image to a panel containing other components

Tags: java, swing

I have a login form in Java panel, with user name / password fields.

I would like to add a background image below this login-form.

What is the best way to achieve this?

Extra bonus for providing sample code, as I have a hard time figuring this out.

Comment: Uhm ... where should I start? Oh yeah, [here: http://tinyurl.com/so-hints](http://tinyurl.com/so-hints). Read that link. Then go back and read it again, please. Also: if you told us what technology you are talking about, then we *might* be able to help you (Swing? AWT? JSP? JSF? SWT? ...).

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5912913/how-can-i-put-a-jbutton-on-an-image

Comment: I want to only offered `Extra bonus for providing sample code, as I have a hard time figuring this out.` here comings answer http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/dialog.html and http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/label.html and http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/icon.html for all JComponets inside JLabel please to set opaque(false);

Answer (score 12):

Two options from the top of my head:

1. Override the paint method of the panel containing the login form to paint the background image before drawing the child-components.
2. Do the following

   1. Create a background image panel (override the paintCompanent method to draw the image).
   2. Set the layout-manager of this panel to BorderLayout
   3. set `opaque(false)` on the panel containing the login form,
   4. Add the login form panel to the background panel with BorderLayout.CENTER.

Demo of the second approach:

```
import java.awt.*;
import javax.swing.*;

class BgPanel extends JPanel {
    Image bg = new ImageIcon("water.jpg").getImage();
    @Override
    public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
        g.drawImage(bg, 0, 0, getWidth(), getHeight(), this);
    }
}

class LoginPanel extends JPanel {
    LoginPanel() {
        setOpaque(false);
        setLayout(new FlowLayout());
        add(new JLabel("username: ")); add(new JTextField(10));
        add(new JLabel("password: ")); add(new JPasswordField(10));
    }
}

public class FrameTestBase extends JFrame {
    public static void main(String args[]) {
        JPanel bgPanel = new BgPanel();
        bgPanel.setLayout(new BorderLayout());
        bgPanel.add(new LoginPanel(), BorderLayout.CENTER);

        FrameTestBase t = new FrameTestBase();
        t.setContentPane(bgPanel);
        t.setDefaultCloseOperation(EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        t.setSize(250, 100);
        t.setVisible(true);
    }
}
```

[image]

Comment: nice code +1, (main method should be wrapped into invokeLated)

Comment: Hmm.. I'm not entirely sure it has to be like that. It is the call to `setVisible(true)` that *realizes* the UI. (IIRC, only `setVisible(true)`, `show` and `pack` realizes the UI, which means that there is no need to do stuff on the UI thread until then)

Comment: last two codeslines `pack(if exist :-)` + `setVisible(true)` should be wrapped in all cases, another methods as you suggested

Comment: `null` in the `drawImage` method, should be `this` (`JPanel` is an `ImageObserver`).  If you put a UI over a white BG before taking a screen-shot, the rounded corners will fit in nicely with the page colors of SO. For further tips on making screen-shots, see [How do I create screenshots?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/99734/how-do-i-create-a-screenshot-to-illustrate-a-post).

Comment: two excellent points. Actually I'm surprised my screen-shot program doesn't save it as a transparent gif. :-)